# How to share references to dlls across multiple projects in a visual studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have multiple base console projects nested within a single solution in Visual Studio. Each project creates a reference to the same base dlls.

[image]

How can I create a centralized references or lib section so that all projects within the solution can reference that centralized location without having to duplicate the same base references to the same dlls over and over again for each project?

Comment: You centralize the code by creating a class library. You reference that library from multiple project. Now you want to centralize the reference itself ?

Comment: Add your library as a project, then you can reference this project to all your console projects.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, most of your **References** appear to be **.Net Framework Class Libraries**. You don't have to worry about those.

If you are re-referencing the same **custom libraries**, it is better to include the Library's source as a **Project** within your **Visual Studio Solution** and add **Project References** to that **Project** in every other **Project** where it is needed.

**Example: Adding a Project Reference**

[image]

If you don't have access to the source code of some of the custom libraries, then what I usually do is, create a **\Libraries** folder at the root folder of the Solution Source folder, and add file references to the individual DLLs from the other Projects within the solution. This way, if 1 or more of your DLLs gets updated / upgraded, you just replace the copy in the **\Libraries** folder and all your referencing projects will point to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid having to reference those libraries from each individual project. But if you are looking to do the same references for a large number of projects - or if you just have some favourite references you want added to each new project you add - then Visual Studio has that capability - it's called a [template project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx).

Create your project the way you want it (it will most likely be a class library, although you can do a UI based one as well), then click `File`->`Export Template`, which brings up the following wizard:

[image]

Then the next time you go `File` -> `Add` -> `New Project` your new template will be listed just like my example on here:

[image]

If you already have a whole lot of established projects that you want to add the same reference to (and it isn't available as a nuget package so you can't use the nuget package manager), then there is a more hardcore way. Visual Studio project files are XML, so you can right click on a project in your Solution Explorer, select `Unload Project`, then right click again on the project and select `Edit` to open the project file as XML. You can then copy paste the Reference nodes containing the references you want to propagate. Do be careful to adjust any relative paths where necessary.

[image]

If you need to do this in a bulk way then open the project files in Notepad++ and do your copy paste operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can't escape it. You need references in your project, you will have to reference them. If you have third party dlls then you can put them in a single folder and reference them in desired projects from there.